# SUM of the Table cell values and show total on bottom end

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET and still learning by doing self-studies. So In my ASP.NET MVC application on the view, there are tables that I load the data and show to the user. Here I want to show the `Total` value at the end of the Amount Cell by `sum` the `Invoice Amount` column data. The data type is `decimal`. I'm struggling to do it because I'm still not good at javascript. So can I get help here? Thanks.

This is my Table

```
 <table class="table">
   <tr>
     <th> Inoice Number </th>
     <th> Invoice Amount </th>
     <th> Attachment </th>
     <th></th>
   </tr> @foreach (var item in Model.PaybillInvoiceDetailsList) { <tr>
     <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoice_No) </td>
     <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoice_Amount) </td>
     <td>
       <a href="@Url.Action(" RetrieveImagePbI", new { id=item.Id })" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
         <img width="100" height="100" border="0" class="m1-1" align="center" src="@Url.Action(" RetrieveImagePbI", new { id=item.Id })" />
       </a>
     </td>
   </tr> }
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `@Model.PaybillInvoiceDetailsList.Sum(i => i. Invoice_Amount).ToString("0.##")`

The full changes can be

```
 <table class="table">
   <tr>
     <th> Inoice Number </th>
     <th> Invoice Amount </th>
     <th> Attachment </th>
     <th></th>
   </tr>
   @foreach (var item in Model.PaybillInvoiceDetailsList) { <tr>
     <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoice_No) </td>
     <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Invoice_Amount) </td>
     <td>
       <a href="@Url.Action(" RetrieveImagePbI", new { id=item.Id })" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
         <img width="100" height="100" border="0" class="m1-1" align="center" src="@Url.Action(" RetrieveImagePbI", new { id=item.Id })" />
       </a>
     </td>
   </tr> }
   <tr>
    <td colspan"3">Total</td>
    <td>@Model.PaybillInvoiceDetailsList.Sum(i => i.Invoice_Amount).ToString("0.##")</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```